# Takenoko: What happens if you draw a card that has an existing pattern in the garden?

Tags: takenoko

What if you draw a objective card that has a specific pattern, and it already exists in the garden, for one reason or another.

Examples:

- You draw a plot card and that exact same shape is already existing in the garden (including the right parameters). Can you just show your objective card as *fulfilled* and get the points without doing anything else?
- You draw a gardener card and you need 3 four-level bamboo in the garden. If there's an existing four-level bamboo in the garden, do you only need to do 2 more?

What happens in each example?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> You draw a plot card and that exact same shape is already existing in the garden
>   (including the right parameters) Can you just show your objective card as *fulfilled* and
>   get the points without doing anything else?

Yes. At any point in your turn, you can play as many fulfilled objective cards from your hand as you like. I've found this often happens at the end of the game... drawing a card in hopes that the objective is already fulfilled is a decent strategy.

> You draw a gardener card and you need 3 four-level bamboo in the garden. If there's an 
>   existing four-level bamboo in the garden, do you only need to do 2 more?

Yes, provided they're the same color. As it often happens with objective cards, other players may be configuring the garden to suit your objectives without even knowing it.

Comment: While your answer is correct *per se*, the rulebook lists an advanced variant, where should you draw an objective card that has already been fulfilled, you have to discard it and draw another one.

Answer (score -2):

> Yes. At any point in your turn, you can play as many fulfilled objective cards from your hand as you like. I've found this often happens at the end of the game... drawing a card in hopes that the objective is already fulfilled is a decent strategy.

On https://pl.boardgamearena.com/ version of Takenoko, when you draw already fulfilled objective, you need to pick another one ;)

Comment: Picking another objective when the one you draw is fulfilled is a variant that can be played to make the game harder, but is not the basic ruleset.